# Function that contains BlockRead() cannot access 'Result' variable

Tags: file, delphi, file-read

I want to create a function that saves a file content into string. I used BlockRead() for that but it gives me a really weird behavior.

I have created the following fileToString() function that actually reads only one byte from the file and then tries to return a constant 'foo' string as a Result. It all starts with Button1Click function and a choose-file dialog which works great.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);

    private
      selectedFile: string;
      FileIntoString: string;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation
{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  function fileToString(fileName: String): String;
  var
      aFile   : File;
      oneByte : byte;
  begin
    Result := '';

    if fileName <> '' then begin

      AssignFile(aFile, fileName);
      Reset(aFile);

      BlockRead(aFile, oneByte, 1);    //Brakpoint 1
      Result := 'foo';                 //Brakpoint 2

      Reset(aFile);
      CloseFile(aFile);
    end;
  end;

var
  dlg: TOpenDialog;
begin
//CHOOSE FILE
  selectedFile := '';
  dlg := TOpenDialog.Create(nil);
  try
    dlg.InitialDir := '.\';
    dlg.Filter := 'All files (*.*)|*.*';
    if dlg.Execute(Handle) then
      selectedFile := dlg.FileName;
  finally
    dlg.Free;
  end;

  FileIntoString := fileToString(selectedFile);
end;
end.
```

When I execute that, I get a error message 'access violation at 0xfe317469:read of address 0xfe317465' and the app crashes.

When I pause program in Breakpoint 1, before the execution of `BlockRead()`, local variable 'Result' has value ' ' [empty string, as assigned in the begging of the function] and local variable 'fileName' has value of the string of the file path.

After executing `BlockRead()` and pause in Breakpoint 2, I get 'Inaccesible value' for both local variables 'Result' and 'fileName' and I get the access violation after executing the `Result := 'foo';` line.

Why do my local variables get affected by the BlockRead()?

Comment: From the (D7) OLH on BlockRead: "The entire transferred block occupies at most Count * RecSize bytes. RecSize is the record size specified when the file was opened (or 128 if the record size was not specified)."  If you want to read a single byte, you should do `Reset(aFile, 1)`, otherwise you will overwrite the stack and get an AV.

Comment: All the more reason not to use old style Pascal IO, and instead use a modern style like TFileStream or TStreamReader

Comment: That's what `TFile.ReadAllText` in `System.IOUtils` was invented for.

Comment: Why do people keep insisting on using 1990 style file I/O thirty years later when there are so many more modern alternatives available? At the very least you could use TStringList. It's only been available since Delph 1.0 was released in the mid-nineties.

Comment: Btw, I mostly agree with the remarks of others, that some classes are more convenient, although they can throw their own set of exceptions just as well. As for TStringList, it's also 25 years old, and it's a 'god' class that does way too much. TStringStream is slightly better, since it will at least not unnecessarily break up your string in lines. But if you really would follow the 'more modern' argument, you should go for more modern classes that are implemented better, and with single responsibility in mind. Or ditch Delphi completely and move to a language like F#.

Comment: @GolezTrol it does not stop in breakpoint 2 because of an exception. It does because of a typical breakpoint I have placed. Doesn't this mean I am in fileToString() scope?

Comment: If it stops on the actual breakpoint, then yes, but if that next line errors, assigning a constant string to result, it means something is seriously wrong and I guess this scope can't really be trusted. I was wrong (comment removed), and @MartynA already nailed it in the very first comment. This [blockread](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=blockread) example uses ReWrite to set a record size. If you [don't do that explicitly](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=rewrite), the default value is 128, so you're overwriting the 127 bytes after `OneByte` with data from your file.